# NSFetchRequest Core Data Swift 3 Backward compatibility

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, nsfetchrequest, ios10

I have converted my code in swift 3. I am using core data in my application. As you know, NSFetchRequest has been changed. 
In swift 2 it was:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UnsyncedTask")
```

In swift 3:

```
let request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = UnsyncedTask.fetchRequest()
```

My question is, It only supports ios 10. How can I make it backward ios compatible? 
I want NSFetchRequest which supports ios 9, ios 10 with swift 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSFetchRequest(entityName:)` is still available in Swift 3.
You can use `if #available` to use the newer API on iOS 10/macOS 10.12
or later, and the older API on older OS versions:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<UnsyncedTask>
if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, *) {
    request = UnsyncedTask.fetchRequest()
} else {
    request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UnsyncedTask")
}
do {
    let results = try context.fetch(request)
    for task in results {
        // ...
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. My iOS Deployment Target is 9.2 and I have an errors in code above in line `request = Settings.fetchRequest()`. The error is saying: **Cannot assign value of type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>' to type 'NSFetchRequest<Settings>'** `The Settings` is just NSManagedObject generated from model in xCode 7

Comment: @MarcinKapusta: But you are using Xcode 8 now? I tested it with a new Xcode 8 project.

Comment: @MartinR Yes I'm using xCode 8 now. Do I need to regenerate my models with xCode 8?

Comment: @MarcinKapusta I strongly think so. Xcode 8 creates a fetchRequest method for each entity.

Comment: @MartinR I regenerated my models. It seems that now everything is correct :) What is important You don't need this `if` because on generated model You have this method even in iOS 9 so checking condition if this is iOS 10 is unnecessary I think.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry I'm wrong. Now I see the compiler complains about this `Ambiguous use of 'fetchRequest()'`

Comment: @MarcinKapusta I corrected answer. Now it should work fine.