# Supporting a NSManagedObject fetchRequest() class method in iOS 9 and 10

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

iOS 10 introduced a new class-level `fetchRequest()` method in `NSManagedObject`.

Like lots of other developers, I had created my own extension on `NSManagedObject` which had a `fetchRequest()` method.

The compiler now rightly complains about this when I'm trying to build to support iOS 10 (with a deployment target of 9.0).

What's a non-terrible way (i.e. I'm not renaming the method and all of the call points) to continue supporting iOS 9 and 10 with this codebase?

The extension currently looks like this:

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        return NSFetchRequest(entityName: self._entityName())
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your extension look like? – Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503915/nsfetchrequest-core-data-swift-3-backward-compatibility.

Comment: I  don't know  if renaming the method can be avoided, since there is not "if not available" check in Swift. But I may be wrong of course.

Comment: You're not often wrong, @MartinR :D

Comment: Why do you need the extension at all? For each entity, `Entity.fetchRequest()` is auto-generated in Xcode 8 and returns a `NSFetchRequest<Entity>`.

Comment: Well, that's another story :D The generated method conflicts with the new one at the NSManagedObject level unless you use type annotation, and I don't think the typed requests are supported in iOS 9, are they?

Comment: I think that the typed request work on iOS 9 as well, but I haven't tested it yet.