# NSPersistentContainer & UnitTests with iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios10

I have an issue with my Core Data setup for Unit Tests.

I use the default/new Core Data stack setup in my AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "GenericFirstFinder")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
}
```

And for testing I have a custom function to create a managed context

```
func setupInMemoryManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "GenericFirstFinder")

    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
    description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })

    return container.viewContext
}
```

I have an extension to find the first item given a predicate.

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func first(with predicate: NSPredicate?, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> Self? {
        return try _first(with: predicate, in: context)
    }

    fileprivate class func _first<T>(with predicate: NSPredicate?, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> T? where T: NSFetchRequestResult, T: NSManagedObject {
        let fetchRequest = self.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return results.first as? T
    }
}
```

Here's the issue.

This test passes:

```
func testExample() {
    let context = setupInMemoryManagedObjectContext()
    let entity = try! Entity.first(with: nil, in: context)
    XCTAssertEqual(entity, nil)
}
```

but if the persistentContainer loading is triggered in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext // end of laziness
    return true
}
```

then I get the following error

> failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException",
>   "executeFetchRequest:error:  is not a valid NSFetchRequest."

The error comes specifically from this line in _first()

```
let fetchRequest = self.fetchRequest() // fetchRequest  is <uninitialized> in that case
```

But if I modify the test to create an entity first, the test runs fine again (the XCTAssertEqual is different of course…):

```
func testExample() {
    let context = setupInMemoryManagedObjectContext()
    let firstEntity = Entity(context: context)
    let entity = try! Entity.first(with: nil, in: context)
    XCTAssertEqual(entity, firstEntity)
}
```

So for some reason, creating a new entity (without saving the context) seems to put things back in order.

I guess my stack setup for testing is screwed up, but I haven't figured out why. Do you understand what's happening and what is the proper way to set things up?

I'm using Xcode 8.3, Swift 3.1 and the deployment target is iOS 10.3.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know that `self` in scope of a class function would bind to the Class type. Learnt something new here.

Comment: Hey. Why don't you abstract self a bit from the storage. It doesn't make too much sense to test CoreData in ur UnitTests. Better approach - is to fake data you getting from CoreData to test your _own_ logic. Making your components testable without dependencies also can help to make ur app code better and more reusable.

Comment: @OlegShanyuk some parts have to be tested with the storage. Some could/should even be tested with SQL storage and not in-memory storage: subqueries can work with in memory storage while failing with file storage.

Comment: @Nycen think the parts which _should_ be tested with a storage - actually could be tested by mocking storage. As you try to separate things a bit - you will benefit a lot.

Comment: @OlegShanyuk By using InMemory storage I'm already mocking storage, separating further would be stubbing.

Comment: @Nycen exactly :) And therefore - you finally test ur own code, not CoreData :)))

Comment: @OlegShanyuk I'm trying to tell you that my unit tests already separate things by using mocking and stubbing. You can't make a bug disappear by separating, you just limit its impact, and I already do that ;)

Comment: @Nycen nice :) ok, probably you want to wait till context is initialised then )

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a Core Data problem in the Unit test target (maybe also when generics are used). I also encountered it at work, this is a solution we have:

```
func fetchObjects<Entity: NSManagedObject>(type: Entity.Type,
                  predicate: NSPredicate? = nil,
                  sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil,
                  fetchLimit: Int? = nil) throws -> [Entity] {

    /*
     NOTE: This fetch request is constructed this way, because there is a compiler error
     when using type.fetchRequest() or Entity.fetchRequest() only in the test target, which
     makes the fetchRequest initialize to nil and crashes the fetch at runtime.
     */
    let name = String(describing: type)
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: name)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your contribution. I'm trying to understand why it crashes, this is similar to what I'm doing and what MathewS posted, but I'd like to understand why it crashes. Maybe it's an Apple bug though…

Comment: Yeah, I would report a radar

Comment: I contacted Apple TS, we'll see how that goes.

Comment: @Alessandro the answer from Apple TS was "I am pretty sure that the issue you saw is a bug in Core Data"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the class function `fetchRequest` and didn't know it existed until looking it up for this question.

I [looked up](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640605-fetchrequest) [some](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66333) [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528071/supporting-a-nsmanagedobject-fetchrequest-class-method-in-ios-9-and-10) but have to admit I still don't understand what's happening.

Recently I've been using the automatically generated classes that Xcode creates that for each entity includes a `fetchRequest` method that looks like this:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")
}
```

Using that as a format I changed a line in your `_first` function to this:

```
fileprivate class func _first<T>(with predicate: NSPredicate?, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> T? where T: NSFetchRequestResult, T: NSManagedObject {

    // let fetchRequest = self.fetchRequest()
    // (note that this wouldn't work if the class name and entity name were not the same)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: T.entity().managedObjectClassName)

    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return results.first
}
```

Which for me prevents the error - I'm posting this to see if it helps you but I'm going to have to investigate some more to understand *why* this works.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that my temporary workaround is *exactly* that… It's definitely worth an upvote but it's not the answer I'm looking for.